# all( generator ) returns True when it should return False

Tags: python, numpy, generator, canopy

I want to check if a string contains all the keywords. I am using the [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) distribution.

For example:

```
string  = 'I like roses but not violets'
key_words = ['roses', 'violets', 'tulips']
```

I've read that the `all` function would serve me well.  When I use this function in the following way

```
if all( keys in string.lower().split() for keys in key_words):
    print True
```

Then `True` is returned.

I would expect `False` to be returned since `tulips` is not in `string.lower().split()`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could not reproduce - I get `False`.

Comment: Me too returns false, are you sure you are not doing - `if not all( keys in string.lower().split() for keys in key_words)` or using `any()` ?

Comment: 100% Sure http://i.imgur.com/ifJ0Wdr.png

Comment: Add this line: `from __builtin__ import all` before your if statement and see if that helps.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have a `from numpy import *` in your code. `numpy`'s `all` method does not handle generators well.

```
[1]: string  = 'I like roses but not violets'

[2]: key_words = ['roses', 'violets', 'tulips']

[3]: if all( keys in string.lower().split() for keys in key_words):
         ...:         print True
         ...:

[4]: from numpy import *

[5]: if all( keys in string.lower().split() for keys in key_words):
        print True
         ...:
True
```

---

If the context is beyond your control, then you can use `from __builtin__ import all` to revert `all` to its default version in your file. However, the recommended method is to either do a selective or a qualified import of `numpy`.

Comment: Oh, that might be the case.  I'm working in Enthought Canopy.  Thanks

Comment: Whenever possible, use the official distribution, which takes care not to do things like mask built-ins.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks for the advice.